# Android: How to Serialize a Typeface

Tags: java, android, serialization, android-typeface

I want to past a `Typeface` through an `Intent` (more specifically a class containing a `Typeface` through an `Intent`) but can't because the class isn't `Serializable`. I tried creating a container class like so:

```
public class SerializableTypeface extends Typeface implments Serializable {

}
```

But got an error because `Typeface` has no default constructor. But when looking for parameters to put in the constructor I couldn't find any constructors for a `Typeface`.

So how do I serialize a `Typeface`?

Answer (score 1):

`Typeface` does not have any public or protected constructors. The only constructor is `private`, and as such you cannot extend the `Typeface` class.

One possibility is to store the `Typeface` instance in your object as a `transient` field, and additionally store the information needed to generate the `Typeface`. These fields could be parceled/serialized, and the `Typeface` could be lazy-loaded as needed.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to achieve this would be to store the Typeface name as a String and parse it on the "other side".

For example:

```
String typefaceName;

Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(), typefaceName);
```